# Spring Security custom validation without using user password involved

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I was wondering if in Spring Security is possible to lock all endpoints of a rest api, and to do a login by doing a custom validation without using the username and password at all.

It is like create a custom validation method that receives a token and not user/pass.  The method will then validate the token with third party that has already validated the caller.

This sounds familiar to OAuth2 only that the backend API needs to be secure by spring, and at the same time it is not the OAuth2 client:

1. We are building a login feature.
2. We have a client (mobile app), backend (REST like endpoints Spring MVC), and an AuthProvider for OAuth2/OpenIdConnect flows.
3. The OAuth/OpenIDConnect flow happens only between the mobile and OpenIDProvider.  (an initial call happens from mobile to backend to provide some details for oauth flows)
4. Once the authorization succeeded, the mobile app receives an auth_code, and only then the backend is called from the app to "Login" which means validate the auth_code, exchange for access_token, and create user session. (we need to have a session).
5. As you see backend kind of "login" in the sense that needs to receive the auth_code only, and validate it with the AuthProvider before creating a session.

Thank you very much!

Any comments, or references are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security determines if a user is authenticated by looking at the `SecurityContext` in the `SecurityContextHolder`. This means you can authenticate the user however you like using the following:

```
boolean userIsAuthenticated = ...
if(userIsAuthenticated) {
    Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
    Authentication result = ...
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(result);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rob Winch!  Following your advise I was able to use a custom filter and provider to handle custom validations.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring Security** is a very flexible framework that publishes a variety of interfaces that allow the user to customize the behavior as need be.

I'd recommend the following resources to learn how to go about this:

- [Architecture Deep Dive in Spring Security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rnOsF3RVQc)
- [Spring Security Custom Authentication Provider](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider)
- [Spring Security Custom AccessDecisionVoters](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-voter)
- [Spring Security Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!  The links are very usefull and the video is just great!